# Trilateration example in java

Tags: java, geolocation, trilateration

I am currently working on a program that utilizes RSSI to determine location based on signal strength. Does anybody know where a working java example is of trilateration? I couldn't find any online.

The program will basically need to take in 3 distances, which are the distances derived from the RSSI's and then the latitude and longitude of the three points and then determine the user's location using 2 dimensional trilateration (I'm ignoring the height of each beacon for now).

I saw a Python one on here, but I don't know Python well enough to understand it.

Comment: Does this help? http://code.google.com/p/talking-points-3/source/browse/trunk/WifiPosition/src/TalkingPoint/thejoo/Trilateration.java?r=109

Comment: That is the current code that I based mine off of but there appears to be problems when two or three beacons are extremely close together or when they are co-linear.

Comment: Girish, I ended up using your link and found a way to account for when beacons are coplanar. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: @GirishRao: +1 for your link :)

Comment: @GirishRao, I want to ask you if the rssi value used in the code you provided is in db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference for anybody with the same problem.

I just used the link Girish provided.
http://code.google.com/p/talking-points-3/source/browse/trunk/WifiPosition/src/TalkingPoint/thejoo/Trilateration.java?r=109

but be aware you have to account for when coordinates are coplanar as this isn't accounted for in the code.