# Convert coordinates of trilateration to position on picture or svg

Tags: python, math, location, beacon, trilateration

I'm working on a project to track a bt device using three bt readers in a room. This already works fine, I have some data.

I hope, I have done my math correct thus I can calculate my position using trilateration. Well, works fine on my paper sheet and arbitrary python script.

I used following tipps:

[Trilateration C# How to get back into "normal" coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50317591/trilateration-c-sharp-how-to-get-back-into-normal-coordinates)

[Trilateration example in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997922/trilateration-example-in-java)

and finally
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100448/finding-location-of-a-point-on-2d-plane-given-the-distances-to-three-other-know

As I know the coordinates of my 3 receivers in "the real world" and distances, I ask my self how to transform this informations onto my 2D picture (or svg).

For instance, how do I convert my three distances 3m, 5m and 6m into a picture with 600x800 pixel. How to I set the position of the readers onto the picture? Any suggestions or real world hints? What happens if I either zoom in or zoom out of the picture? How to find the coordinate for my position marker on my picture derived from real data?

Thanks

Comment: Please augment your question with some specifics:  Show the raw numeric data that you want to transform into in image, and also add some kind of sketch that shows the kind of image you would like to generate from the numeric data.  You might draw this image by hand and attach a picture, or use drawing software to generate the example.

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially asking how to draw a map of a small area.

Take the corners of the 600x800 image and decide where they should land in the real world. Ideally the they should make a rectangle of the same 3 by 4 shape, so that the conversion factor of real world distance to pixels is the same on horizontal and vertical. After that it's just linear interpolation.